# What's wrong with my IF formula? Combining IF, AND/OR, and COUNTIF into one

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Thanks for pointing that out @Scott Craner. I made that edit to my formula, but it still doesn't work. Here's what I mean:

I wrote a simple formula in column H that checks if the Item# is on the sheet named SharePoint. If it's not, the cell will say 'Add to SP.'

> =IF(COUNTIF(SharePoint!N:N,A2)=0,"Add to SP","")

But what I really want is for the cell to say this only if sheet SharePoint doesn't haven the Item# AND columns D or F say one of the phrases in the OR statement. I added a combination of AND and OR statements to the above formula to accomplish this. This formula is in column I.

> =IF(AND(COUNTIF(SharePoint!N:N,A2)=0,OR(D2="Transferred",D2="Needs Validation",D2="No PPAP Required",D2="Closed W/O Approval",F2="Supplier Late")),"Add to SP","")

[Here are a couple of test cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ktlx.png) - neither item# is in sheet SharePoint (which the simple formula in col. H correctly diagnoses), AND they have one of the phrases in the OR statement. So column I should say Add to SP, but the formula just returns a #N/A error.

If I'm not mistaken, I think all syntax errors have been removed. I feel like the logic of the formula makes sense, so what have I done wrong? Did I make some sort of error when I combined the AND and OR statements?

Answer (score 2):

You have a `)` out of place

> `COUNTIF(SharePoint!N:N,A280=0)`

Should be

```
COUNTIF(SharePoint!N:N,A280)=0
```

So:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(SharePoint!N:N,A280)=0,OR(B280="Transferred",B280="Needs Validation")),"Add to SP","")
```